# Export JSON value in gitlabci from curl

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm using a gitlabci job. In this job, I'm trying to get and export JSON value from curl :

```
  script:
  - >
    message=$(curl --request GET ${HOST_ADDR}/path)
  - echo $message.object1.object2.value
```

Script is running fine but

> echo $message.object1.object2.value

is displaying the whole object, not only the embedded value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with jq tool :

```
 - >
    message=$(curl --request GET ${HOST_ADDR}/path)
 - echo ${message} | jq -r '.object1.object2.value'
```